# Apache Directory Forbidden

Tags: linux, apache, permissions, webserver, http-status-code-403

I am trying to set up a owncloud server using httpd. In my `/var/www/html` I set the owner and group to `apache:apache` and permission of 644.

In my httpd.conf file I have the following.

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

<Directory "/var/www/html/owncloud">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

I am able to read the php files in the document root, however, when I browse to `/owncloud` I am getting a 403 Forbidden error.

In my error log I am getting the following.

```
(13)Permission Denied: access to /owncloud denied
```

Am I missing any configuration?

Comment: It is not a *folder* but a *directory*

Answer (score 1):

You should usually set the user/group to `www-data:www-data`, see [the Owncloud guide](http://doc.owncloud.org/server/5.0/admin_manual/installation/installation_source.html), unless you have a changed webserver configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my two cents. (Others have posted similar answers).
I just moved from Linux Fedora 14 to Fedora 20,
then downloaded/installed Apache (which is no longer on
the install DVD), and ran into this "403 You don't
have access" problem, until I found that SELunix
was the culprit.  Depending on your flavour of
Linux, this might apply to some of you as well.
To find out whether SELinux is active, enter
"getenforce". If you get "Enabled" then look
in "/var/log/audit/audit.log".
You might see lines like

> ... denied  { getattr } ... comm="httpd"
>   path="/var/www/html/index.html"

Then decide whether:

1. You DON'T want/need SELunix. Then edit
   "/etc/selinux/config" and change the relevant
   line to "SELINUX=disabled", then reboot.
2. You DO want/need SELunix. Then study SELunix
   and change whatever settings. (I can't help
   you with this, since I opted for 1 above.)  :D